# minSdkVersion Error when uploading APK to Android Market

Tags: android, sdk, version, google-play, apk

When I try uploading the APK to the Android Market, I get this message:

> Market requires the minSdkVersion to
>   be set to a positive 32-bit integer in
>   AndroidManifest.xml.

But I have defined `android:minSdkVersion` in my Manifest...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.mkainc.tabwidget"
          android:versionCode="7"
          android:minSdkVersion="7"
          android:versionName="2.1">

...
```

Comment: Unrelated, but is it a coincidence that your code version 7 is 2.1, or are you thinking thats because of the API used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SDK information needs to be contained in a uses-sdk tag:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) for details.

Comment: maxSdkVersion has ben deprecated.

Comment: Correct, it says so in the link I posted. However, I copied and pasted the above code from said link as well - they list it since it's still supported. But maxSdkVersion is indeed not a good tag to use.